# "erupted in violence" vs. "erupted into violence"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, prepositions, british-english

I have come across both in major newspapers. Are both correct? What kind of phrase is this?

1. Erupted in violence
2. Erupted into violence

This is the example sentence.

"This led to riots in 2005, when the country's impoverished banlieues(suburbs) erupted into violence."

As mentioned in my comment I think it may have something to do with the word following in/into. (e.g) The crowd erupted in unison. Not into.

Answer (score 1):

I found an example [here](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/in-to-or-into). I'm no expert at the English language, but this is the example:

"When you use **in**, you're indicating position.

*Her phone was **in** her pocket.*

When you use **into** in a sentence, you're indicating movement; an action is happening.

*She stuffed her phone **into** her backpack.*"

Comment: Not really. I think it may have something to do with the word following _in/into_. (e.g) The crowd erupted in unison. Not _into_.

Comment: Alright, well, that's what I found. Sorry it wasn't quite what you were looking for; makes sense to me